# How to make two object not overlap?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need to form a street with several houses of various sizes without overlapping while staying on the same line.

Code so far :

```
def rue(nb_maisons):
    speed (0)
    x = (-300,300)
    i = 0
    while i<nb_maisons :
        cote= randint(100,120)
        up()
        coord1= randint(-100,300)
        coord2= -300 + cote   

    
        z= coord1
        while  z<cote+1       
        list =list +z   
        #add z 
    
        list d = d + coord1
    
        goto(coord1,coord2)
        maison(cote)
    
        else coord1#not in list
        coord1= randint(-300,300)
    
        i=i+1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You question would imply that you've managed to make houses but need help keeping them from overlapping, which seems reasonable.  But the fact is the code you provided doesn't run as it is syntactically incorrect at several points.  Focus your question on what you need immediate help with in your program.